# I have to code a linear search but my code doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, search

I need to write a code that does a linear search on a character within a string. I have to do it without using any inbuilt functions.

The program should output the index of the found character.

If the character isn't in the sentence it should output -1.

I have tried writing the code but it inputs the sentence and character but then doesn't work.

```
def linear_search(intList,target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    while count < len(intList):
        if intList[count] == target:
            count = count + 1
            found = True
            break


    return found

sentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
character = input('Enter a character: ')
character_found = linear_search(sentence,character)
if character_found:
    print("The character is", count, "on the index")
else:
    print("The character is -1")
```

Comment: Your `while` loop is an infinite loop. If `intList[0]` isn't equal to `target`, then `count` is not incremented.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I shall check.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
def linear_search(intList, target):
    count = 0
    while count < len(intList):
        if intList[count] == target:
            return count

        else:
            count += 1

    return -1
```

Problems with your code:

1. If the value at the current index is equal to `target`, then you've found it! You can just return `count`. If not, *then* you want to increase `count`. Currently, your code does the opposite.
2. Your code returns `found`, which means that it will only ever return `True` or `False`. There is actually no need for a `found` variable, since you can break out of the function by returning, but in any case you should be returning `count`.
3. Outside the function, you attempt to refer to `count`. That won't work, because `count` is a *local variable*: a new instance of `count` is created for every time you run the function, and destroyed after the function returns. Incidentally, this is another reason you should be returning `count`, not `found`: you can just check if `count == -1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting stuck in an infinite loop, because you only update the `count` variable after the solution is found.

Proper implementation of the while loop:

```
def linear_search(intList, target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    while count < len(intList):
        if intList[count] == target:
            found = True
            break
        count = count + 1
```

I also suggest using a for-loop instead of a while-loop to prevent this mistake:

```
def linear_search(intList, target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(intList)):
        if intList[i] == target:
            found = True
            count = i
            break
    return found
```

I also noticed some other mistakes, but since they aren't a part of your question I will let you try and solve those yourself first.